# Mac OS X Python tkinter.TclError with Popup Menu

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, tkinter, tcl

I am trying to summon a Popup menu with the tkinter python GUI toolkit on Mac OS X. This works just fine on Windows, but throws this TclError on Mac OS X. I have ActiveTcl 8.6 installed on the machine. All the other GUI elements (so far) have worked just fine. Do you guys have any ideas how to fix this? The traceback is below.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "gui.py", line 57, in popup
    self.menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2778, in post
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'post', x, y)
_tkinter.TclError
```

Comment: If it's come from the Tcl side, it's been shorn of all information that we might use to track it down. “Something went wrong in the menu's `post` method” is all we can say right now…

Comment: What more information could help?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049790/python-2-7-x-tkinter-popup-menu-throwing-tclerror), you can fix this by binding the menu to a Frame or Tk object. Something like:

```
self.config(menu=self.menu)
```

if `self` is your root window.