# Python 2.7.x Tkinter popup menu throwing tclError

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to create a popup menu in Tk, but when I get to the part where the menu is to be displayed (menu.post), I get a "TclError" exception. I don't understand why, and when I try to step into the Tk code to see what's going wrong, I only get a couple of steps in before I suddenly can't step into code anymore and the exception bubbles up. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think it has to do with how I'm creating the menu.

```
class Bugger(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # setup window attributes
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.attributes('-topmost', 1)

        # set starting positions and values
        self.TotalAssigned = "0"
        self.TotalResolved = "0"

        # add first label
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text=self.TotalAssigned, bg="red")
        self.label1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        # add second label
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text=self.TotalResolved, bg="yellow")
        self.label2.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        # add right-click menu
        self.menu = tk.Menu(master=self, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.ExitMenu)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Preferences", command=self.Preferences)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-2>", self.popup)

    def ExitMenu(self):
        exit(0)

    def popup(self, event):
        self.menu.post(event.x_root,event.y_root)

    def Preferences(self):
        print ("In preferences dialog")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    bugger = Bugger()
    bugger.mainloop()
```

The TclError exception takes place on the line self.menu.post(event.x_root,event.y_root)

Edit: Here's the error I'm getting. I don't know why I didn't include this the first time.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/robb/source/Bugger.py", line 73, in popup
    self.menu.post(event.x_root,event.y_root)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2797, in post
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'post', x, y)
```

TclError

Any advice for me?

Comment: Please show the error

Comment: Edited the original comment to add error message.

Comment: It would really help if you created an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Most of the code in your question isn't necessary to reproduce your problem, and code that _is_ necessary is missing.

Comment: Try replacing the `event.x_root,event.y_root` with numbers and see if it gives you an error.

Comment: So I updated the question to just mcve code. And @JonahFleming, I tried changing event.x_root and event.y_root to just numbers, and that didn't work. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I think that you have to assign the menu to the root window. To do this add the line `self.config(menu=self.menu)`. Other wise you are calling the menu without it having a window to display on.

**Edit**

Also it can't be set to `overrideredirect` because it does not support popup menus. It also gives an error if you right click on the window when it is not in focus.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the answer @jonah! Whoops. I spoke too soon. I tried it, and it didn't change anything. I'm still getting the TclError when I call self.menu.post.

Comment: I have fixe the answer @Goishin but it might stuff up your app. Sorry… :(

Comment: Well, when I right-click now several times in a row, I get a bunch of exceptions and sometimes a popup menu. So, I guess technically, you're right. But this does totally break my app. Maybe a right-click menu is not the way to go :(

Comment: @Goishin Make sure the window is in focus before you click to get rid of the   errors I think. Also, why did you need it in overrideredirect?

Comment: overrideredirect seems to get rid of things like the window close, minimize, maximize. This is a little app that just has two little floating numbers that you can move anywhere on your screen. They're supposed to be always ontop, and quite small and unobtrusive. They just give you the number of bugs assigned to you by querying jira's rest api. If I leave off overrideredirect, then you get the min, max, close buttons. It looks and works great as it is. But it's ugly with the window buttons.